# AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'mktime'

Tags: python, import, mktime

I'm getting this attribute error either because I'm importing the modules or else referencing them incorrectly.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime, time, tzinfo
```

with

```
def utc2local (utc):
    epoch = time.mktime(utc.timetuple())
    offset = datetime.fromtimestamp (epoch) - datetime.utcfromtimestamp (epoch)
    return utc + offset
```

called by

```
(utc2local(rise), utc2local(set))
```

which gives me - AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'mktime'

I have changed my imports to

```
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime, tzinfo
```

but I get - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

How should I be calling the modules or what should I be using to reference them, thanks

Comment: using the predefined `set` keyword doesn't help I bet... we'd need a [mcve] & stacktrace BTW.

Comment: You appear to have confused [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) (a module that has a `mktime` function) and [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) (a class that has no such method). If you need to access both, you'll have to alias one (e.g. `import time as time_`).

Comment: I would recommend `import time` and `import datetime as dt` then if you need access to `datetime.timedelta`, for example, you can do `dt.timedelta`.

Comment: ok I have changed to`import time as t` and `epoch = t.mktime(utc.timetuple())` which gives the error `datetime.time' object has no attribute 'timetuple` - all circles to me, I'm afraid

Comment: @tamus. A `datetime.time` is just a generic time of day - it's not tied to a any specifc date.

Comment: @ekhunoro. I'm trying to convert sunrise and sunset times to local time as I have daylight saving. I would calculate the times each day but also need to convert them to local time in order to use them because at the moment they are 1 hour off. Can't work out whats wrong with 'timetuple' though

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to import datetime
Just do it:

```
import time
time.mktime(your_time)
```

or

```
from time import mktime
mktime(t)
```

source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_mktime.htm

Comment: Except that OP *does* also want to use functionality exposed by `datetime`.